# Delete row from databricks table if not existing in incoming dataset

Tags: sql, pyspark, databricks, ansi-sql

I have an delta table in Databricks. Let's call it `df` for this instance. A mocked data set below.

```
df
+---+---+----+
## |id|label|
## +---+----+
## |  1| foo|  
## |  2| bar|  
## +---+----+
```

I'm using incoming data sets (let's call it `new_df`) to `merge` into `df`.

```
new_df
+---+---+----+
## |id|label|
## +---+----+
## |  2| bar|  
## |  3| fob|  
## +---+----+
```

Code I'm using to merge:

```
MERGE INTO default.df AS df
USING new_df
ON df.id = new_df.id

WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET *

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, label)
    VALUES (new_df.id, new_df.label);
```

This works pretty well and gives me a result like this:

```
+---+---+----+
## |id|label|
## +---+----+
## |  1| foo|
## |  2| bar|  
## |  3| fob|  
## +---+----+
```

The only issue is that I'd like for row [1, foo] to be removed since the data is no longer in new_df (and is not 'active'). What would be the best way to achieve this? Please note that Databricks ANSI SQL `merge` command is limited and doesn't have options such as `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE/TARGET`. Ideally the solution is all done in Databricks Spark SQL but I'm open to suggestions in Pyspark as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need to update data from table with new_df records and remove records that are not in the new_df you should overwrite instead of merge.

Maybe I got it wrong and if that's the case I'm sorry, but it really seems like a full load if you need the old table to have the exact same records as the new_df.

Comment: Thanks @Thomaz. I largely agree with you. The only thing is that as part of the `MERGE` command, I'm also adding some metadata such as "UPDATEDTC" to keep track of if and when an existing data comes with new value.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to use another SQL command. It seems that because of ANSI SQL being limited (compared to TSQL, etc.), the actions needed to be broken down. The second part of my code became something like this:

````
```
DELETE FROM
  df
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT
      id
    FROM
      df2
    WHERE
      df2.id = df.id
  )
````